# MATLAB polynomial fit selective powers

Tags: matlab, least-squares, polynomials

I have 2 vectors x and y to which I want to fit a polynomial as `y = f(x)` in MATLAB.
I could have used `polyfit`. However, I want to fit only selective power terms of the polynomial. For example, `y = f(x) = a*x^3 + b*x + c`. Notice that I don't have the `x^2` term in there. Is there any built-in function in MATLAB to achieve this?
I am not sure if simply ignoring the coefficient that MATLAB gives for `x^2` is same as fitting the polynomial without `x^2` term.

Comment: No it isn't. Do you have the Curve fitting toolbox? If so, have a look at the [**`fit`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the fitting toolbox and want to just remove a possible coefficient. If that's the case, here's a way to do it.

```
%What is the degree of the polynomial (cubic)
polyDegree = 3;

%What powers do you want to skip (x^2 and x)
skipPowers = [2, 1];

%This sets up the options
opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'LinearLeastSquares' );

%All coefficients of degrees not specified between x^n and x^0 can have any value
opts.Lower = -inf(1, polyDegree + 1);
opts.Upper = inf(1, polyDegree + 1);

%The coefficients you want to skip have a range from 0 to 0.
opts.Lower(polyDegree + 1 - skipPowers) = 0;
opts.Upper(polyDegree + 1 - skipPowers) = 0;

%Do the fit using the specified polynomial degree.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( x, y, ['poly', num2str(polyDegree)] , opts );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the curve fitting tool box (see @thewaywewalk's comment), or anyway, it is easy to use `mldivide`:

```
x=rand(10,1);                  % your x data
y=5*x.^3+2*x+7+rand(10,1)*.01; % some y data with noise
[x.^3 x ones(size(x))]\y       % least squares solve to y = a*x^3 + b*x + c
```

gives

```
ans =
    4.9799
    2.0211
    6.9980
```

Note that "simply ignoring the coefficient that MATLAB gives for x^2" is definitely not the "same as fitting the polynomial without x^2 term".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @user1543042 answer was more suitable for me because I was trying to emulate behavior of Excel LINEST function in MATLAB.

Comment: The approach of @user1543042 is nice because it gives you the goodness-of-fit statistics and confidence intervals. This simpler `mldivide` approach gives exactly the same result, though.

Answer (score 0):

In recent Matlab versions you can do it easily with a GUI by selecting the `APPS` tab and then the `Curve Fitting Tool`.

For example, I define:

```
x = 1:10;
y = x + randn(1,10);
```

I then select those variables as `X data`,  `Y data` in the tool and I choose a `custom equation` defined as `a*x^3 + b*x + c`. The results are:

[image]